# writing the content of the list data structure into a text file

Tags: java

I have just basic query that is I have tried to write the data of the arraylist type string into a file so i have added the extra method as shown below..

```
private static final String Newline = "\r\n";

 private void addContent(List<String> recordforfile, BufferedWriter bw) throws IOException {

        for (String s : recordforfile) {
            bw.append(s);
            bw.append(Newline);


    }
```

now my query is inside the the add content method that the line..bw.append(s); will write the list data (that is the string data in the list of each index) into the file or it should be bw.append(s.tostring()) , please advise

Comment: `String.toString()` is redundant.  Not just that, but I don't observe you closing this stream anywhere.

Comment: What do you think it shld be? Its already a string , so what will toString() do?

Answer (score 1):

It's already a string. Adding `.toString()` to it will do exactly nothing, because it'll just return the same `String` object.